# Laravel Collection Sum Multiple Columns in Collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have been reading about collections in Laravel.  Currently I am aware of how to use it however I have a question about the `sum()` function.

According to the docs it can be used like this:

```
collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])->sum();
```

And also like this:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'JavaScript: The Good Parts', 'pages' => 176],
    ['name' => 'JavaScript: The Definitive Guide', 'pages' => 1096],
]);

$collection->sum('pages');
```

Which is fine and I understand, however now I have an array with nested objects and I would like to know how I can achieve something like this in laravel:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'JavaScript: The Good Parts', 'pages' => 176, 'price' => 100.00],
    ['name' => 'JavaScript: The Definitive Guide', 'pages' => price, 'pages' => 150.00],
]);

$collection->sum(['pages', 'prices']);
```

Which would obviously return either an array like this:

```
[1272, 250]
```

or on collection / object like this:

```
{"total_pages": 1272, "total_price": 250}
```

in short I would like to know how I can sum and return the results of multiple columns in a laravel collection instead of doing this twice:

```
$collection->sum('pages');
$collection->sum('price');
```

Since i assume that would cause multiple loops over the collection or am I wrong?

Comment: Is this to solve a current issue, or just for knowledge? I'm interested in what people come up with

Comment: Both current issue and knowledge.

Comment: What's wrong with array-summing and array access? I.e. `$sums = $collection->sum(["pages", "prices"]); $pageSum = $sums[0]; $priceSum = $sums[1];`? Or are you saying that `$collection->sum(["pages", "prices"]);` doesn't work?

Comment: I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: Your question makes it sound like it is: *"`$collection->sum(['pages', 'prices']);` Which would obviously return either an array like this..."*, but I get it; that's not supported. Follow-up; what's wrong with a manual loop/addition?

Comment: Coz each set of data returned could contain like a 100 or more records. II'm not exactly sure how ```collect()``` works but I assumed doing a 100 loops per request might be slower.

Comment: `collect()` turns an `array` into a `Collection`, which is just a wrapper for easier array functions/organization. Behind the scenes though, it's likely that `->sum()` is iterating over the array records anyway; so doing a `foreach()` loop and incrementing `$sums["price"]` and `$sums["pages"]` manually might be more efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to use the `pipe` method to pass the collection to a callback. Within the callback you could achieve what you're wanting to do.

```php
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'JavaScript: The Good Parts', 'pages' => 176, 'price' => 100.00],
    ['name' => 'JavaScript: The Definitive Guide', 'pages' => 314, 'price' => 150.00]
]);

$result = $collection->pipe(function ($collection) {
  return collect([
    'total_pages' => $collection->sum('pages'),
    'total_price' => $collection->sum('price'),
  ]);
});
```

Comment: But won't this just add the sum of book and the sum of prices and return the result?

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood your original question. I've updated my answer to do what you'd want.

Comment: Wow great, didn't know I can do this! Thank you, going to read more about using pipes!

Comment: Have no idea why both my question and yours were down voted though.

Comment: Someone else came by and did a random downvote. I upvoted your question to bring it back to 0. Seemed like a legitimate question to me, and I think others will find it useful they google something similar in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [`code behind the sum() function`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L1551-L1562), we can see that internally `$collection->reduce()` is used to collect the data. So we should be able to use the same code to achieve what you are looking for:

```
return $collection->reduce(function ($result, $item) {
    if ($result === null) {
        $result = [
            'pages' => 0,
            'price' => 0,
        ];
    }

    $result['pages'] += $item['pages'];
    $result['price'] += $item['price'];

    return $result;
}, 0);
```

To get a more generic solution out of it, you could also create a macro on the `Collection` class within one of your service providers:

```
Collection::macro('sumMultiple', function ($columns) {
    return $this->reduce(function ($result, $item) use ($columns) {
        if ($result === null) {
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                $result[$column] = 0;
            }
        }

        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $result[$column] += $item[$column];
        }

        return $result;
    }, 0);
});
```

You can then use the new function with `$collection->sumMultiple(['pages', 'price'])` and you will receive a result like `['pages' => 123, 'price' => 234]`.

Pleas be aware that `sumMultiple` does not support nested arrays at this moment (i.e. dot notation access to fields does not work).